# objective-c multiple button click method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 3 buttons on my main view (btn_easy, btn_medium, btn_hard) that I dragged onto my main view via the xCode Interface Builder Library - Round Rect Button item.  after declaring them in my ViewController.h and ViewController.m files like so:

```
 //ViewController.h
 IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_easy;
 IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_medium;
 IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_hard;

 @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_easy;
 @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_medium;
 @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton  *btn_hard;

 //ViewController.m
 @synthesize btn_easy,btn_medium,btn_hard;
```

I then proceeded to make Connection Outlets in the Interface Builder to the "File's Owner" by clicking on the btn_easy, btn_medium, btn_hard (sequentially) in my View, going to Connection Inspector and dragging the "New Referencing Outlet" to "File's Owner" (not sure if that was what I should have done here).

My method to make the buttons work in my ViewController.m file is as follows:

```
 -(void)buttonPressed: (id) sender{
      NSLog(@"button clicked = %@",sender);
 }
```

My problem is that when I click any of the buttons nothing appears in my NSLog when I should actually see "button clicked = btn_easy" when btn_easy is clicked, so on and so forth.

Please help.....
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused outlets and actions, I think. An outlet - as you've defined - gives one class an outward connection to another. An action is something a control can trigger.

You should add buttonPressed to your .h as:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

To have Interface Builder recognise it as an action. You can then control-drag a link from a button to your class (which seems to be file owner) and connect the two up. Which, I guess, you'll want to do three times.

This is the same as dragging a link from 'touch up inside' to your class, that being when buttons take effect on iOS.

Comment: OK that makes the buttons throw an action (NSLog alert) to the console however I was expecting it to throw "button clicked = btn_easy" and the other two as well but I actually get: "button clicked = <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x5f17730; frame = (109 241; 104 37); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x5f176b0>>"

Comment: How do I just get the name of the button clicked? so I can then do an IF statement for the three separate actions that should happen depending on if easy, medium, or hard is clicked?

Comment: Also, how do I know when and which methods to declare in the .h file before I use it in the .m file?

Comment: The 'sender' that is passed to buttonPressed: is the button itself. It doesn't know what you're calling it or what it was called in Interface Builder. If you have outlets set up too then you can just do if(sender == btn_easy), etc to find out which button is talking to you. You can name the action methods absolutely anything you like — that's why you have to link them up in Interface Builder. I think IB still looks in the header file only to find actions and outlets, so you need to put them there (and save) before switching out of Xcode. Xcode 4 should make all this a lot easier.